# Alterar style dinamicamente através do JS

Tags: javascript

Em um progressbar, por exemplo, com este style:

```
#progress {
background: #000000;
border-radius: 13px;
height: 20px;
width: 400px;
padding: 3px;
}

#progress:after {
content: '';
display: block;
background: white;
width: 300;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Eu preciso alterar o preenchimento da bar em função do tempo. No caso, eu preciso alterar o width do progress:after. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Eu preciso alterar o preenchimento da bar em função do tempo. No caso, eu preciso alterar o width do progress:after. Como posso fazer isso?

Não é possível alterar diretamente o estilo de um [`pseudo-elemento`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos), como é o caso do [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

No entanto, é possível adicionar regras específicas diretamente nos estilos interpretados pelo browser.

Para tal podemos utilizar o método [`.addRule`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuucnct.php) do objeto [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet).

No entanto, é valido ressaltar que esse método não é suportado em todos os browsers.

Para garantir o funcionamento do código, vamos criar uma função auxiliar responsável por verificar se o browser tem suporte ao método `.addRule`. Em caso negativo, vamos trabalhar com a reescrita direta da propriedade **CSS** que queremos alterar.

A função auxiliar criada para o exemplo foi:

```
function changeRule(selector, property, value) {

    var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];

    if (stylesheet.addRule) {
        stylesheet.addRule(selector, property + ': ' + value);
    } else {

        var rules = stylesheet.cssRules;

        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            var rule = rules[i];
            if (rule.selectorText == selector) {
                rule.style[property] = value;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Segue um exemplo do uso:

```js
var INCREMENT_FACTOR = 25;

function changeRule(selector, property, value) {

  var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];

  if (stylesheet.addRule) {
    stylesheet.addRule(selector, property + ': ' + value);
  } else {

    var rules = stylesheet.cssRules;

    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {

      var rule = rules[i];

      if (rule.selectorText == selector) {
        rule.style[property] = value;
      }

    }

  }

}

var progressInterval = setInterval(function() {

  var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

  var maximumWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(progress).getPropertyValue('width'));

  var currentWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(progress, '::after').getPropertyValue('width'));

  var newWidth = currentWidth + INCREMENT_FACTOR;

  changeRule('#progress::after', 'width', newWidth + 'px');

  if (newWidth == maximumWidth) {
    clearInterval(progressInterval);
    alert('success!');
  }

}, 500);
```

```css
#progress {
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 13px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 3px;
}
#progress:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: white;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"></div>
```

Leia mais sobre o assunto em [Modify pseudo element styles with JavaScript](http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/).

Comment: @Sergio acredito que agora esteja ok. Na última alteração não funcionou porque o método `.insertRule` no FF acaba por substituir todo o estilo ao invés de adicionar.

Comment: Boa! Já dei `+1` acho que agora ficou ótimo. Se quiseres explicar esse _feature detect_ `stylesheet.addRule` seria excelente :P

Answer (score 5):

No HTML5 existe a tag [**`<progress>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) que serve justamente para isto. A diferença é que, ao invés de modificar a largura de um elemento, você vai precisar alterar somente o seu valor (atributo `value`).

```js
var $progress = document.querySelector('progress'), // Pegando o elemento
    MAXIMUM   = $progress.max;                      // Pegando o valor máximo: 100

/* Aumentando o valor a cada 1 segundo para exemplificar... */
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  $progress.value++;
  if($progress.value >= MAXIMUM)
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```

```html
<progress max='100' value='0'></progress>
```

---

Também é possível customizá-la como qualquer outro elemento HTML. A diferença é que, como as propriedades não são padronizadas, será preciso procurar pelas propriedades e prefixos para alterar a aparência:

```css
.custom {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  height: 10px
}

/* cor de background da barra */
.custom::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #fff
}

/* cor de background do valor de progresso */
.custom::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #9b59b6
}

.custom::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #9b59b6
}
```

```html
<h4>Default:</h4>
<progress max='100' value='50'></progress>

<h4>Customizada:</h4>
<progress class='custom' max='100' value='75' data-value=''></progress>
```