# Como criar uma barra de progresso dinâmica considerando todos os campos de um formulário?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Estou tentando criar uma barra de progresso um pouco diferente das que encontrei por aí. [Esta](http://www.bootply.com/106527) por exemplo, pega os `values` dos campos e joga no `aria-valuenow` da barra de progresso.

No meu caso, quero pegar os campos que vão sendo preenchidos e ir calculando o percentual e atualizando a barra em tempo real.

Consegui fazer usando apenas um tipo de seletor, mas não consigo usar mais de um. Veja com apenas `selects`:

```js
$("select").one('change', function() {
        var totalSelect = $('select').length;
        console.log(totalSelect);
        var atual = document.getElementById('progress').getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
        console.log(atual);
        if (atual == 0) {
            var percentual = 100 / totalSelect;
        console.log(percentual);
            $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentual + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percentual);
        }
        else {
            percentual = (100 / totalSelect) + atual;
           $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentual + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percentual);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="select1" class="control-label">
                <select id="select1" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <label for="select2" class="control-label">
                <select id="select2" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" id="progress"
                         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No <kbd>[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15351/)</kbd>.

Porém, quero fazer com todos os principais seletores de formulário: `input`, `select`, `textarea`, `radio` e `checkbox`.

Tentei algo assim pra colocar com `input` também, mas não deu certo:

```
$("select, input").one('change', 'keypress', function() {
}
```

Mas não rolou. Criei um exemplo abaixo de onde parei, com vários campos, e pra facilitar pra quem quiser ajudar, criei também um
   <kbd>[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t8qzd4c1/2/)</kbd>.

```js
$("select").one('change', function() {
        var totalSelect = $('select').length;
        var totalInput = $('input').length;
        var total = totalInput + totalSelect;
        console.log(total);
        var atual = document.getElementById('progress').getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
        console.log(atual);
        if (atual == 0) {
            var percentual = 100 / total;
        console.log(percentual);
            $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentual + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percentual);
        }
        else {
            percentual = (100 / total) + atual;
           $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentual + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percentual);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="select1" class="control-label">
                <select id="select1" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <label for="select2" class="control-label">
                <select id="select2" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="input1" class="control-label">
                <input id="input1" type="number" class="form-control">
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <label for="input2" class="control-label">
                <input id="input2" type="text" class="form-control">
            </label>
            <br><br>
</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="radio radio-inline" for="radioSim">
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radioSim" name="radioName1" value="sim">
                    <b>Sim</b></label>
                <label class="radio radio-inline" for="radioNao">
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radioNao" name="radioName1" value="não">
                    <b>Não</b></label>
                <br><br>
                <label class="radio radio-inline" for="radioSim2">
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radioSim2" name="radioName2" value="sim">
                    <b>Sim</b></label>
                <label class="radio radio-inline" for="radioNao2">
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radioNao2" name="radioName2" value="não">
                    <b>Não</b></label>
                    <br><br>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
<label class="checkbox" for="Check1">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Check1"/>Check1
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="Check2">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Check2"/>Check2
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="Check3">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Check3"/>Check3
</label>
    <br><br>
<label class="checkbox" for="Check1B">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Check1B"/>Check1B
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="Check2B">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Check2B"/>Check2B
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="Check3B">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Check3B"/>Check3B
</label>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
<label class="control-label" for="textArea1">TextArea1
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea1" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea>
</label>
<br><br>
<label class="control-label" for="textArea2">TextArea2
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea2" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea>
</label>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-7"></div>
    <label class="control-label">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    </label>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" id="progress"
                         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não seria algo como: `$("select, input").one('change keypress', function() {`

Comment: Ah, é isso mesmo! Já tinha até desligado o note, daí vi pelo celular e pensei WTF não é possível... kkkk liguei de volta e bingo. Valeu! Agora preciso pensar melhor em alguns detalhes, porque quando escolhe um radio devia ser x2 (porque passou dois campos), e quando escolhe em checkbox pode ser até mais de 2... e parece que pra textarea não funciona colocado apenas o input...  amanhã vou ver melhor, valeu por enquanto! @Chun

Comment: Ah, e só pra constar, também tive que colocar o `parseInt` nas variáveis...

Comment: hehehe xD sim, tens que adicionar também o `textarea` como selector e por aí em diante. Eu estava a pensar numa outra forma de abordar isso, em vez de apontar para os selects, criar uma class responsável por isso, calcular quantos elementos existem com esta class e adicionar 1 valor a cada elemento encontrado no documento para depois então calcular o valor total e exibir a percentagem na barra de progresso, mas ainda não construí mentalmente como vou fazer isso para começar a desenvolver. E receio que depois possa não ser bem esta maneira que queiras fazer as coisas :P

Comment: hehe Pois é, antes de deitar ainda pensei "Eita, era só adicionar o textarea!" hehe Acho que daria certo com classe mesmo né, só daria mais trabalho pra incluir uma classe comum a todos... e não sei muito bem como funcionaria, porque neste caso, pelo que entendi, cada comportamento esperado é adicionado na mesma sequência, `select` é com o `change`, `textarea` e `input` fica `keypress` e `keypress` etc...  Eu acho que desse jeito já vai resolver [continua]

Comment: Mas tem alguns detalhes para os quais ainda precisarei de ajuda... depois criarei um fiddle pra ajudar na sua resposta :D... valeu! @Chun

Comment: Então, na verdade percebi que nem precisava estar usando o `keypress`, isso estava fazendo com que os aumentos ocorrem em triplo quando era em `text` ou `textarea`. É que achei que o `change` funcionava apenas para os `selects` ... daããã rsrs Mas tá saindo, eu modifiquei também a contagem, já dividindo os `radios` por 2, só não consegui ainda resolver a questão dos `checkboxes`, porque no caso é possível escolher mais de um, mas não é necessário. Então queria que quando escolhesse um, já avancasse o total daquele grupo de checkboxes, e se escolher outro não avançar nada...

Comment: Segue o fiddle atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/t8qzd4c1/4/ E @Chun aguardo sua resposta, nem que seja apenas com a solução que já postaste como comentário, mas se der pra resolver essa questão dos checkboxes eu ficaria grato em dobro! rsrs E olha, se quiser apresentar outra solução eu gostaria muito de ver... mas queria conseguir implementar dessa forma nem que fosse apenas pelo desafio (e eu usar depois a sua solução hehe)...Valeu!

Comment: Pois, essa parte de selecionar vários `checkboxes` mas apenas contar como 1 também não sei como resolver, talvez os mais experientes te possam ajudar nisso. Eu até adicionava esse comentário como resposta, mas como seria uma resposta de apenas poucas linhas, acho que não vale a pena estar a postá-la como resposta. Esta solução é melhor do que aquela que eu tinha em mente. Mas agora também estou interessado em saber como essa parte dos `checkboxes` irá funcionar :)

Comment: @gustavox precisa ser uma resposta usando Bootstrap?

Comment: Não @renan. Pode ser sem bootstrap... mas no caso acho que seria relativamente simples adaptar sua solução (JS principalmente) ao Bootstrap, ou não? De qualquer forma não precisa considerar o boostrap.

Comment: Então @renan e aquela outra pergunta, é porque alguns campos estarão ocultos e/ou serão opcionais, então pensei em aplicar uma classe nestes opcionais, e quando eles fossem modificados a conta modificaria. Porque senão, quando estes campos abrem a barra completa antes do tempo...

Comment: Já vou dar uma olhada lá @gustavox :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Progresso

A tag [**`<progress>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) foi introduzida no HTML5 justamente para exibir o progresso de uma tarefa, ou seja, não é necessário manipular a propriedade **`width`** de um elemento. Convenhamos, atualizar o **`value`** do progresso é mais semântico que modificar a largura de um elemento, não!?

Embora ela seja renderizada com a aparência do sistema operacional, dá para estilizá-la com CSS normalmente, como se fosse qualquer outro elemento. Inclusive já postei [**uma resposta com um exemplo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91998/4808). Então a primeira observação é esta: Se o documento é HTML5, seja legal e use a tag **`progress`**.

#### Eventos

Sobre os eventos de mudança, eu usaria a função [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ao invés da [**`one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) pois a segunda irá esperar pelo evento uma única vez, após este ser disparado o *listener* será removido.

Se o usuário, por ingenuidade (ou por zuera mesmo) resolver modificar um campo em que o evento já foi disparado, o valor do progresso continuará marcando que o campo já foi preenchido e está OK, mesmo colocando um valor incorreto.

Com a função **`on()`** você pode fazer uma validação e modificar o valor do progresso de acordo com a validade dos campos, incrementando ou decrementando o valor atual.

#### Elementos

Utilize classes para agrupar elementos ou até mesmo [***data attributes***](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), assim fica mais fácil definir um evento para um determinado grupo (e.g **`.minha-classe-de-agrupamento`**) do que buscar por tags **`select, input, textarea...`**.

Então, uma forma de fazer:

```js
$(function() {

  var $progress         = $('#progress'), // Barra de Progresso.
      $progressElements = $('.progress'), // Elementos que devem ser checados
                                          // para modificar o valor da barra.
      TOTAL             = $progressElements.length; // Total de elementos.

  
  $progressElements.on('blur, change', function() {
    
    // Faz um filtro com o total elementos válidos.
    // Nesse caso, campos que não estejam "em branco" e que não estejam marcados
    // como ':invalid'.
    var valid = $progressElements.filter(function() {
      return ($(this).val() || $(this).prop('checked')) && !$(this).is(':invalid');
    }).length;
    
    // Calcula a porcentagem e altera o valor da barra.
    var percent = (valid * 100) / TOTAL,
        current = $progress.val();
    
    var increase = percent > current;
        
    var transition = setInterval(function(){
      if((increase && current >= percent) ||
        (!increase && current <= percent))
          clearInterval(transition);
      
      var value = $progress.val();
      value = increase ? value+1 : value-1;
      current = value;
      
      $progress.val(current);
    }, 10);    
  });
});
```

```css
progress, .progress {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<progress id='progress' max='100' value='0'></progress>

<form>
  <input class='progress' type='text' placeholder='Nome' />
  <input class='progress' type='email' placeholder='Email'/>
  <textarea class='progress' placeholder='Sobre mim...'></textarea>
  <input class='progress' type='radio' name='foo' value='s' required/>
  <input class='progress' type='checkbox' name='bar' value='n' required/>

  <select class='progress'>
    <option selected disabled>País</option>
    <option>Brasil</option>
    <option>Portugal</option>
  </select>
  <button type='submit'>Registrar</button>
</form>
```

No caso eu agrupei os elementos pela classe **`.progress`**, mas como dito anteriormente você também pode utilizar um atributo **`data-*`** para agrupar todos os elementos que serão checados no momento de alterar a porcentagem de progresso.

Comment: Legal @renan. O problema da tag `<progress>` é que não é suportada nos navegadores mais antigos, mas ajudou bastante. Talvez eu até mude pra progress mesmo, e deixe a barra só pra navegadores que suportem HTML5. No caso dos checkboxes e radios buttons, como você resolveria? O checkbox, como é opcional por natureza, teria que ao selecionar um de um grupo, já contar como todos tendo sido selecionados, e depois se clicar em outro checkbox (do mesmo grupo) não alterar nada... +1

Comment: Você pode usar o atributo [**`required`**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp). Editei a resposta, seria isto?