# Atualizando ProgressBar em JSF

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, bootstrap-3

Boa Tarde,
Estou fazendo um método assincrono que faz buscas no banco de dados(oracle), e retorna em uma arquivo de Excel. Dentro do meu Método tem o `for`

```
@Async
public synchronized void carregarApresentacoesParaExportar() {
    try {
        ...............
        for(int i = 0 ; i < qtdePages; i++){
            if(isBaixado){
                percent = 0;
                qtdePages=0;
                break;
            } else {
                exportar.configurarValores(transacoes.getContent());
                if(transacoes.hasNext()){
                        transacoes = getService(enumType).buscarPaginado(getFiltro(), new PageRequest(transacoes.nextPageable().getPageNumber(), MAX_EXPORTAR));
                }
                percent = ((i * 100) / qtdePages);
            } 
        }
        ...............
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        LOG.error(e, e);
        geraMsgErro("txt.erro.download.excel");
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(arquivo); 
    }
}
```

Utilizo a váriavel `percent` para dizer a cada incrementação quanto está concluído. 
Na minha `view` eu faço assim

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{notificacaoMB.percent}" labelTemplate="{value}%"
                                                styleClass="animated" global="false">
                                                <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{notificacaoMB.onComplete}" />
                                            </p:progressBar>

                                            Outra ProgressBar

                                            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                                <div style="width: #{notificacaoMB.percent}%" id="progress" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="#{notificacaoMB.percent}" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
                                                    <span >#{notificacaoMB.percent}%</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Ativo com este command

```
<h:commandButton title="#{messages['label.iniciar']}"
                                                value="#{messages['label.iniciar']}"
                                                actionListener="#{notificacaoMB.carregarApresentacoesParaExportar()}"
                                                onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();PF('startButton').disable();"
                                                widgetVar="startButton"
                                                rendered="#{notificacaoMB.possoIniciar()}"
                                                styleClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

Está funcionando com o `Primefaces`. Porém a solução que quero é a do `Bootstrap progress progress-striped`.

fica assim em execução:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja utilizando `Bootstrap` eu não dei um Start no component , só consigo ver o progresso se eu der um Refresh na página ......

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço funcionar utilizando `Bootstrap`?
Tentei essa solução
[Como criar uma barra de progresso dinâmica considerando todos os campos de um formulário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104384/como-criar-uma-barra-de-progresso-din%C3%A2mica-considerando-todos-os-campos-de-um-fo) .
Mas não consegui implementar, como faço com Jquery/Javascript ?

Comment: Se você colocar o progressBar dentro de algum componente do prime (`p:outputPanel`, por exemplo), depois disso fornecer um id para esse componente e do back end fazer `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("id-do-componente");` não fundiona? (vale lembrar que `id-do-componente` deve ser o id "completo", considerando todos os ids que contém esse componente. Ex: `id-form:id-tab:id-panel`)

Comment: @IgorVenturelli , provavelmente deve dá certo, porque já está funcionando com prime.... mas eu preciso de uma solução que não utiliza prime, pois nesse projeto estamos retirando tudo de primefaces e deixando sómente bootstrap...

Comment: Ah tá.. pode ser componente padrão do jsf? Deve ter um `<h:outputPanel />` ou algo do tipo.. Funcionaria do mesmo jeito :P

Comment: Pode ser sim? estou tentando, mas você teria algum exemplo ?

Comment: Respondi cara... Você disse que estão removendo o Primefaces do projeto.. mas pelo menos a dependência do Java pode existir? A classe `RequestContext` é do pacote `org.primefaces.context.RequestContext`...

Comment: Conseguiu? Mas se você retirar o primefaces não terá mais a capacidade de requests ajax por componentes.. Ou estará usando somente os componentes nativos do jsf..

Comment: o jeito é continuar usando primefaces já que ainda tem muitas outras dependências para retirar no projeto. kkk

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar seu componente do bootstrap dentro de um componente do JSF e atualizar o componente do JSF pelo ManagedBean:

```
<h:form id="meuForm">
    <h:panelGrid id="meuPanel">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div style="width: #{notificacaoMB.percent}%" id="progress" 
                aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" 
                aria-valuenow="#{notificacaoMB.percent}" 
                role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
                <span >#{notificacaoMB.percent}%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

---

```
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean
public class MeuManagedBean {

    @Async
    public synchronized void carregarApresentacoesParaExportar() {
        /* ..códigos... */
        percent = ((i * 100) / qtdePages);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("meuForm:meuPanel");
        /* ..códigos... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda não está startando o componente. enquanto o outro do primefaces já inicou via ajax, este do progress-bar ainda fica parado, só quando da um refresh na pagina ele funciona... fiz desse jeito no managebean..

Comment: @ArthurEdson que estranho cara.. Vê se o id ta certo no `update("")`.. Vai no navegador e inspeciona o elemento do progressbar.. vê se o id do panel está certo..

Comment: Sim o id está correto estou fazendo o update("form:meuPanel")... Não starta o componente.... vou ter que pensar em outra solução que utilize Jquery ou Javscript, mas muito obrigado.